# Accessing Spark and/or PySpark from Flask Web App

Tags: python, apache-spark, flask, web-applications, pyspark

I have an installation of Apache Spark in `/home/ubuntu/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7'`

I have a flask app in `/home/ubuntu/flaskapp`

I also have a jupyter notebook installed. I have also installed a module name `findspark` to make finding the Spark installation easier.

In the Jupyter notebook, it works as expected. If I just jump in and type
`import pyspark`
it throws an error that there is no module named `pyspark`. This is expected. So i have to use findspark. So it only works, as expected, if i do:

```
import findspark
findspark.init('home/ubuntu/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7')
import pyspark
```

With the flaskapp, however, it doesn't work. If i just do the basic file for Hello World, it works just fine and I can see the webpage from it's designated URL. So this works just fine:

```
from flask import Flask

@app = Flask(__name__)
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

However, if i try to use `pyspark` via `findspark` (which i pip installed globally), it does not work. The web page spits out a `500 internal server error`. So this simple code here does not work:

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/ubuntu/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7')

import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

sc = SparkContext()
data = range(0,100)
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
a = rdd.take(2)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "List items are {} and {}".format(a[0], a[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

So my question are:

1) Why does it not work?

2) What is the easiest way to have the script connect to `pyspark`?

**Edit**:

Debugger output:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-11-55:~/flaskapp$ FLASK_DEBUG=1 flask run
 * Serving Flask app "flaskapp"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 156-406-059
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/01/17 19:40:35 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/01/17 19:40:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/01/17 19:40:37 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
18/01/17 19:40:38 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
18/01/17 19:40:38 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
```

Comment: Enable Flask debugger and check the error? And in general - embedding SparkConext in a web application is a really bad idea.

Comment: @user6910411 How would i use debugger? Right now, i don't have to run `flask run` or `python flaskapp.py`. I symlinked the folder to my `/var/www/html` so and then made some changes to the `apache.conf`. Basically, i followed these instructions to create the flask app, so i never had to run a py file. 

https://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/24/running-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2/

Anyway, i did try to run upon your ask, using `FLASK_DEBUG=1 flask run` and all the output is in this gist. 

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/23d69e92e332b83307a6f5fa989f5100

Comment: _could not bind on port_ - make sure that ports are accessible or set free port manually (`spark.ui.port`) and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: dumb question here... how do i do that?

Comment: May suggest starting with Spark 101? :) For example editing `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`. But check if port is occupied first. With `netcat` or similar tool.

Comment: My Spark runs perfectly fine. The challenge is not running Spark, but accessing it from a Flask web app

Comment: As far as I can tell your app works just fine (tested in a sandbox) so this points to specific environment. From log it is clear that there is no immediate problem with Spark paths and that JVM starts and attempts to bind to a port.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on a project running a local Spark cluster on the same server as a Flask web server. I ran into the exact same error as you are, but can't remember exactly what the issue was...

Pretty sure it's related to the lack of arguments provided to the SparkContext at initialization. Need to provide either a SparkConf object, or explicit details on master url, etc.

The below functions in python 2.7, running a local spark cluster on as many cores are available on your server. Let me know if this runs, or if there are additional errors.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

_sc = SparkContext('local[*]', 'nameOfYourSparkContext')
_data = range(0,100)
_rdd = _sc.parallelize(data)
"""Perform your operations on _rdd such as .map(), .collect()
"""
_sc.close()
```